# Java syntax for separating action listeners

Tags: java, swing

Please help me out to separate these `ActionListeners` in a periodic table that I am attempting to complete. When I execute the program and click on 'H', it opens all the other elements and when the others are clicked, it does not work. So I need a way to separate these using any method...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class PeriodicTable
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{    
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Elements");
  frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,1500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);

JButton button1 = new JButton("H");
panel.add(button1);
button1.addActionListener (new Action1());

JButton button2 = new JButton("He");
panel.add(button2); 
button2.addActionListener (new Action2()); 

JButton button3 = new JButton("Li");
panel.add(button3); 
button3.addActionListener (new Action2()); 


}
static class Action1 implements ActionListener 
{        
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{     
 JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("H");
         frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.setSize(1000,1500);
         JLabel label = new JLabel("Hydrogen");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame2.add(panel);
            panel.add(label);       
  }
}   
static class Action2 implements ActionListener
{        
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{     
    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("He");
    frame3.setVisible(true);
    frame3.setSize(1000,1500);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Helium");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame3.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);
        }
}
static class Action3 implements ActionListener
{        
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{     
    JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("Li");
    frame4.setVisible(true);
    frame4.setSize(1000,1500);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Lithium");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame4.add(panel);
    panel.add(label);
        }
}   
}
```

Thanks in advance.
(note: only the first 3 elements are coded for...)

Answer (score 0):

> When I execute the program and click on 'H', it opens all other elements

Only one frame opens for me.

> and when the others are clicked, it does not work.

Each button opens a single frame for me.

However, button 3 opens the wrong frame because you add the wrong listener to the button:

```
//button3.addActionListener (new Action2());
button3.addActionListener (new Action3());
```

Other issues:

1. You should add the components to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.
2. Don't hardcode screen sizes, you never know what size screen other users will be using

So the order of your code might be something like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Helium");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(label);

JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("He");
frame3.add(panel);
frame3.pack();
frame3.setVisible(true);
```

And of course you really don't want to create dozens of separate ActionListeners. You want to make the listener more generic so it can be shared.

Something like:

```
static class Action implements ActionListener
{        
  public Action(String element, String description)
  {
    this.element = element;
    this.description = description;
  }

  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{     
    JLabel label = new JLabel(description);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label);

    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame(element);
    frame3.add(panel);
    frame3.pack();
    frame3.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Then when you create the listener you use:

```
button3.addActionListener (new Action("HE", "Helium"));
```